# Where is Oracle APEX source code framework located

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Recently i start learning Oracle APEX and i have a question (i'm familiar with plsql):

Where is the source code for APEX located, in which schema ?

EG: For this piece of code where can i find APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS souce code :

```
IF :P9_HOW_MANY is NOT NULL and :P9_HOW_MANY > 0 then
IF NOT APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS (p_collection_name => 'CHILDREN') THEN
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(
          p_collection_name => 'CHILDREN'); 
END IF;
APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBERS(
p_collection_name => 'CHILDREN',
p_c001 => apex_application.g_f01,
p_c002 => apex_application.g_f03,
p_c003 => apex_application.g_f04,
p_c004 => apex_application.g_f02 
);
End IF;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer, i will leave this here in case it helps anyone:

APEX_COLLECTION

APEX_ITEM

ETC..

all are public synonyms located in SYS schema and the source code is in APEX_190200 schema on the WWV_FLOW_COLLECTION package.

Comment: FYI the APEX_XXX schema will change when you upgrade versions, e.g. Apex 19.1 was in APEX_190100. There's also a lot of helpful documentation about the Apex packages - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531